# Pandas Issue subtracting a series from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction

I am subtracting a series from a dataframe column.

```
df

                daily_return    daily_weight

2003-01-01T          1.2            62
2003-01-02T          1.3            63
2003-01-03T          1.1            64
 ...
```

and series

```
                    Return
2003-01-01T          1.2            
2003-01-02T          1.3            
2003-01-03T          1.1            
 ...
```

indices are identical datetime indexes.  I use the following sytnax:

```
df['Daily Return'].subtract(s['Return'],axis=0)
```

The result I get is:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Series can't be indexed like that, if your series is called `s` then just do substract(s, axis = 0)

Comment: if I do it that way it times out and doesn't work.  Interesting, if I do `df.join(s)` if gives me duplicate index values for each day.  but the indexes are IDENTICAL.!!

Comment: well, that's a different issue vs your original question.  we can consider the ValueError issue solved, no?

Comment: `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` usually means you have dupes in the index. Maybe check that `s.index.nunique() == len(s.index)`

Comment: @randy - that was it.  It was a bad data issue and had nothing to do with the syntax.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone.

It was actually a data issue.  Data was being somehow transformed and indices in one index was corrupted on import.  code was good.

I would vote myself down one if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic works fine **if** you've correctly defined `df` and `s`:

```
idx = pd.Index(['2003-01-01T', '2003-01-02T', '2003-01-03T'])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Daily Return': [1.2, 1.3, 1.1],
                             'daily_weight': [62, 63, 64]})

s = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Return': [1.2, 1.3, 1.1]})

df.index, s.index = idx, idx

print(df['Daily Return'].subtract(s['Return'],axis=0))

2003-01-01T    0.0
2003-01-02T    0.0
2003-01-03T    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: In my ide my series indicated here says it's a 'dataframe'.  However in my experience i column dataframes behave like a series.  Maybe I'm still doing something wrong?  As indicated above I've tried syntax that address it as a series (e.g.,`s`) and as a dataframe (e.g. `s['Return']`. it fails either way.